# How to keep files accessible after reinstalling linux OS?

Tags: linux, permissions, users

Given a linux server:

- There are two partitions; one is mounted on **/**, and the other is mounted on **/data**.
- There is a user named **alice**.
- **alice**'s uid is 1001.
- **alice** created many private files on **/data**. That is, only the user of uid 1001 can access the files.

Then:

- I clean reinstall the linux OS, and keep the data partition mounted on **/data**.
- I create a new user named **alice**. However, the uid of **alice** is not sure to be 1001. Let's say 1002.

Now:

**alice** cannot access her files on **/data**, because her uid(1002) is not equal to the uid(1001) of the files.

In practice, how to solve the common seen issue?

Comment: Related https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/528109/4778

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either create the user `alice` with a `uid` of `1001` or change the ownership of the files from `1001` to `1002`.

Create a user with a specific `uid`:

```
useradd alice -u 1001
```

`find` all files owned by `1001` and `chmod` them to `alice` (this will also change the `gid` to `alice`'s primary group):

```
find /data -uid 1001 -print0 | xargs -0I{} chown alice: {}
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of options. If you don't have a user on the new system with `uid=1001`, then change alice's uid to that via `usermod -u 1001 -g 1001 alice`. Other option is to change the ownership of the files on `/data` using `sudo find /data -uid 1001 -print0 | xargs -0 chown alice:alice`.